# How can I determine why the pager is not working for the category view in my template?

Tags: template, magento1.9.3

I have installed a templatemonster template and the pager will not display in the toolbar in the category view.  The **product_list_toolbar_pager** block appears to be correct in the **layout/catalog.xml** file:

```
<!--
Category default layout
-->

<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
...
```

`template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` also appears to call the **getPagerHtml** method correctly

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
*/
?>
<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="pager">
        <p class="amount">
            <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>

        <div class="limiter">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select> <?php //echo $this->__('per page') ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>

    </div>
```

The problem is that `$this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager')` returns false in Toolbar.php.  For some reason `$this->_children[$name]` in the `getChild()` function in Abstract.php is not set (where $name is "product_list_toolbar_pager").

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    $pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

    if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {
```

The pager works fine in the **base_default** and **rwd_default** templates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would check to see if the theme does anything with the `product_list_toolbar_pager` block to begin with

Comment: @sfrost2004 Could you be more specific?  I was assuming that **toolbar.phtml**  calling `getPagerHtml()` would be all that is required.  If the data for `product_list_toolbar_pager` is loaded earlier in the code I'm not sure where I would begin looking for it.

Comment: I would start by comparing the catalog.xml from your theme with the catalog.xml from the `base_default` or `rwd_default` themes to see what is different. I would guess that something in the theme is either unsetting the `product_list_toolbar_pager` block (or one of its' parent blocks) or it never gets set at all (depending on what the parent theme is).

Comment: This theme is built off of the **base_default** theme.  The `catalog_category_default` section is identical in the two **catalog.xml** files, except that the modified theme has appended `<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>` to the list of action tags.  The only difference I can find in the parent blocks is in **page.xml** where the parent of the `core/text_list` `content` block is the root block.  The base_default theme calls for `page/3columns.phtml">` whereas my template calls for `2columns-left`, which shouldn't unset `product_list_toolbar_pager`.